# Magento Setting Prices to Zero - Randomly

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, zero

Looking for some help with our Magento 1.9.2 set up.

For the last month or so we've experienced prices changing to zero for no reason. We've tried to work out what could be causing it by disabling/removing extensions, upgrading from 1.7 to 1.9.2, but it's still happening.

Its very random - can go for 2-3 days with no zero prices and then all of a sudden we'll get a batch of up to 20+ products.

The affected products are normally from orders on the previous day and once they have zero'd themselves, and we've reset them back to their true price they don't zero again.

The ONLY link we think we've found is placing manual orders, and the process we use for that.

We are at our wits end tho, Magento is working perfectly apart from this one issue.

Any suggestions?